# Move a color n% towards white

Tags: color, inkscape, color-reproduction

I have an RGB color in Inkscape and the guideline says

> Recommended Brightening of Colours for Artistic Purposes 
>   60 % Towards White
>   80 % Towards White

Unfortunately, the RGB codes of those brightened colors are not given. How would I design such a color in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

- Use the color dialog.
- Select the HSL tab.
- Increase the L-Bar as much as you need.